# x86_64 intel putnbr only prints 1st number correctly

Tags: assembly, printing, numbers, x86-64, nasm

I just started with asm and was trying to write some basic function's. It seems that my write, putchar and putstr work but my putnbr doesn't print correctly. When i try a positive nbr it only prints the first nbr and for all the other nbr's it prints 0's and when i print a negative nbr it prints 400000-something. The code for my putchar is this:

```
BITS    64

extern  ___error
default rel

    section .bss
    buffer  resb 1       ; buffer used for character to syscall write

    section .text
    global  _ft_putchar

_ft_putchar:
    mov     [buffer], rdi    ; input char written to addres
    mov     rsi, buffer      ; address of char passed to write
    mov     rdi, 1           ; set fd
    mov     rdx, 1           ; set amount of char
    mov     rax, 0x2000004   ; set syscall
    syscall
    jc      _error
    jmp     _ret

_error:                      ; function to set errno
    push    rax
    call    ___error
    pop     qword [rax]
    mov     rax, -1

_ret:
    ret
```

putnbr is in recursive and i use the same logic as i use in putnbr in C:

```
BITS 64

extern  _ft_putchar

    section .text
    global  _ft_putnbr

_ft_putnbr:              ; function to print nbr given to it in rdi

_loop:
    xor     rax, rax     ; set rax to 0 
    cmp     rdi, 0
    jnge    _put_dash    ; if nbr < 0, write a '-' and do nbr * -1
    cmp     rdi, 10
    jnae    _put_dig     ; if nbr < 10, write the nbr
    mov     rax, 0
    mov     rax, rdi     ; put nbr in rax
    mov     rbx, 10
    mov     rdx, 0       ; set rdx to 0 (prepare for remainder div)
    div     rbx          ; devide rax by 10 put remainder in rdx
    mov     rdi, 0       ; set rdi to 0 (prepare for function call)
    push    rdi
    mov     rdi, rax     ; mov rax to rdi to do next iteration putnbr with
    call    _ft_putnbr
    pop     rdi
    mov     rdi, rdx     ; remainder div stored in rdx to rdi
    jmp     _put_dig

_put_dash:               ; subroutine for writing dash and inversing nbr
    push    rdi          ; save rdi on stack
    mov     rdi, 0
    mov     rdi, '-'     ; mov the printable char to rdi
    call    _ft_putchar
    pop     rdi          ; get rdi back from stack
    neg     rdi          ; invers nbr to positive
    jmp     _loop        ; go back to loop

_put_dig:
    add     rdi, 48      ; add 48 so nbr is ascii
    call    _ft_putchar  ; write nbr
    ret
```

I tried to push en pop rdi before functions and tried working partly on eax and edi instead of their quadword registers but I haven't found the right way yet. Hope you guys can spot the mistakes!

Comment: Everybody loves debugging miles of undocumented and uncommented assembly code.  Try to add some comments indicating what you think your code is doing.  This way, it's much more pleasant to find your error.  Also, please let us know what operating system you are programming for.

Comment: Also I assume `nbr` is short for “number?”   So `putnbr` is your number printing routine?

Comment: Oke yeah, I will add comments. I realize that like this it will be hard to read

Comment: First clear bug: `mov [buffer], rdi ` moves 8 bytes, since `rdi` is a 64-bit register, but `buffer` has space for only 1 byte.  Make sure you understand the concept of operand sizes, it is a common stumbling block for new assembly programmers since high-level languages handle it for you.  You can do `mov [buffer], dil` instead to operate only on the 8-bit register `dil`, which is the low byte of `rdi`.

Comment: You still haven't said what OS it's for.  It looks like MacOS but please add this to the question.

Comment: Also what is the point of the push/pop of `rdi` around the recursive call to `_ft_putnbr`, when the value you save is just always zero, and you overwrite it again  with the very next instruction `mov rdi, rdx`?  And especially since `rdx` no longer contains the remainder from your division, because the recursive call overwrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Nate, the problem was indeed that I pushed rdi before the call to ft_putnbr instead of rdx.
So after the call rdx was reset and so I just copied a 0 into rdi to putchar.
This segment:

```
    push    rdi
    mov     rdi, rax     ; mov rax to rdi to do next iteration putnbr with
    call    _ft_putnbr
    pop     rdi
```

should be:

```
    push    rdx
    mov     rdi, rax     ; mov rax to rdi to do next iteration putnbr with
    call    _ft_putnbr
    pop     rdx
```

I will also change my putchar, although this has worked until now but i understand it is bad practice